# Prove that a Fibonacci number is greater than $ φ^n$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, recursion, golden-ratio

How can I prove the following:

> If $f_n$ is a number of the Fibonacci sequence and  φ= $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2$, then $f_n >  φ^n$ for every $n >2$?

I have tried using induction but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: $\varphi^1 > 1 = f_1$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the affirmation is valid for $n>2$.

Comment: Then take $n=3$. We have $f_3=2$, but $\phi^3\sim 4.236$, so the claim is not true. In fact, the opposite inequality holds.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589

Answer (score 3):

We have $F_n=\left[ \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}\right]$, so this implies $F_n<\phi^n$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number for a proof. So we have the opposite inequality. Here $[x]$ denotes the nearest integer function.

Comment: This is not true as written. For example, $F_3=2>1.89\dots=\phi^3/\sqrt5$. We have $F_n=(\phi^n-(1-\phi)^n)/\sqrt5$, so $F_n$ is larger than $\phi^n/\sqrt 5$ whenever $n$ is odd. What you get is that $F_n$ is the integer closest to $\phi^n/\sqrt5$, and a little additional argument is needed to see that this still gives $F_n<\phi^n$.

Comment: Sorry, the brackets denote nearest integer function. So $F_3=[1.89]=2<\phi^3$ is correct. But thank you, I corrected the brackets.

Comment: Ah, OK. Had not seen the notation used that way, seems unnecessarily ambiguous. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution sequence of the recursion $g_{n+1}=g_n+g_{n-1}$ satisfies
$$
g_n=f_{n-1}g_0+f_ng_1
$$
Since $g_n=φ^n$ is a solution of this recursion,
$$
φ^n=f_{n-1}φ^0+f_nφ=f_{n-1}+φf_n>f_{n+1}>f_n.
$$