# Prove by induction the $fib(n) \geq (3/2)^{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

So i have this practice question, and i tried to solve it using strong induction, but i'm kinda uncertain on the validity of the proof. Here it goes.

Let the fibonacci sequence be recursivly define so that

$$F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$$

Else if n >= 2
$$F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2} $$

Prove that 
$$F_n \geq (3/2)^{n-1}$$
For all numbers in the set $\{6,7,8,9...\}$

So the way i have proceeded atm is i have done the base case $F_7, F_6$, where after i assume that the inequality holds up to some n and want to prove that it also holds for n+1.

$$    (3/2)^{n} = (3/2) \cdot (3/2)^{n-1} \leq (3/2)^{n-1} + (3/2)^{n-2} \leq F_n + F_{n-1} = F_{n+1}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You should add a lemma that $1\le (3/2)^{-1}+(3/2)^{-2}$. Then the claimed inequality follows.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589

Comment: Your base case is $n = 6$ ("For all numbers in the set $\{6,7,8,9...\}$").

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla that was a typo, thanks for pointing out!