# Prove by induction that $Fib_{n} \geq (3/2)^{n-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I need help with the last inductive steps, can someone help? I hope my formatting is good enough, first time here.

**The case:**

*"Let the fibonacci sequence be recursivly defined so that 
$$F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$$
Else if n >= 2
$$F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2} $$
Prove that 
$$F_n \geq (3/2)^{n-1}$$
For all numbers in the set $\{6,7,8,9...\}$"*

**Basecase:**
$$F_{2} = F_{1} + F_{0} = 1 + 0 $$
$$F_{3} = F_{2} + F_{1} = 1 + 1 $$
$$F_{4} = F_{3} + F_{2} = 2 + 1 $$
$$F_{5} = F_{4} + F_{3} = 3 + 2 $$
$$F_{6} = F_{5} + F_{4} = 5 + 3 $$

$$F_{6} \geq (3/2)^{5} = 8 \geq 7.59 $$

**Induction step:**

We assume the above is true for $n=k$, so now we prove it is true for $n=k+1$

We remember
$$F_n \geq (3/2)^{n-1}$$

$$F_{k+1} \geq (3/2)^{k}$$

We know that

$$ F_{k} = F_{k-1}+F_{k-2} $$
$$ F_{k+1} = F_{k}+F_{k-1} $$
$$ F_{k}+F_{k-1} \geq (3/2)^{k} $$

I'm not quite sure where to go from here, can anyone help? I've looked at [another thread about the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484464/prove-by-induction-the-fibn-geq-3-2n-1), but I don't understand the last part of his equation nor the answers.

In my case we are told that "you may need to use $(3/2)+1 > (3/2)^{2}$", but I don't know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589.

Comment: Ihf, thanks but I already read that actually. Inside the link I post there's also a direction to that exact answer, but I couldn't understand it. 
However, José's answer makes perfect sense to me and is very intuitive - to me atleast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F_k\geqslant\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}$ and $F_{k+1}\geqslant\left(\frac32\right)^k$, then\begin{align}F_{k+2}&=F_k+F_{k+1}\\&\geqslant\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}+\left(\frac32\right)^k\\&=\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}\left(1+\frac32\right)\\&>\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac32\right)^2\\&=\left(\frac32\right)^{k+1}.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, this makes very much sense! <3

Comment: José, how can 

$(3/2)^{k-1} + (3/2)^{k}$ be equal to $(3/2)^{k-1}(1+3/2)$ ?

Comment: I did **not** claim that they are equal. What I claimed was that$$\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}+\left(\frac32\right)^k=\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}\left(1+\frac32\right).$$

Comment: Sorry, just edited my question. How did you find it's the same?

Comment: \begin{align}\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}+\left(\frac32\right)^k&=\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}+\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}\times\frac32\\&=\left(\frac32\right)^{k-1}\left(1+\frac32\right).\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a bunch, José!

Answer (score 0):

Write $F_{k+1}\geq (3/2)^k+(3/2)^{k-1}=(3/2)^{k-1}(1+3/2)$ from here you can finish using the hint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped me to make sense of it all!

Comment: No problem, I am happy it was helpfull