# Prove with induction that $b_{n+1} \geq ({3 \over 2})^{n-1}$

Tags: induction, solution-verification

I need to prove with induction that $b_{n+1} \geq ({3 \over 2})^{n-1} $ $∀ n ∈ \mathbb N$
Sequence is given as $b_{1}=b_{2}=1$ and for every $n \gt 2$ $,b_{n}=b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ so basically fibonacci sequence
I tried to prove it with strong mathematical induction

**Base**:$\quad n=1: 1\geq ({3 \over 2})^{1-1}$ applies
$\quad\quad\quad  n=2: 2\geq ({3 \over 2})^{2-1}$ applies
**Step**: Let $b_{k+1} \geq ({3 \over 2})^{k-1} $ be correct for every k ∈ $ {1,...,m}$

We have to show that $b_{m+2} \geq ({3 \over 2})^{k} $ is also correct.
So we get that $b_{m-1} + b_{m} \geq ({3 \over 2})^{m} $
Solving this gives me $({3 \over 2})^{m} \geq 0$
So for every natural number this inequality holds
Is this correct?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589

Comment: @lhf It's not the same question?

Comment: @Divide1918, if you mean the shifts in the index and exponent, then they are taken care of by choosing $a$ in $ab^n$.

Comment: @lhf, the point of the site is not to mark anything that can/has been generalized as a duplicate. In fact it doesn't even make sense. This is a completely separate question and meant to be proved as such. The spirit of the question is clearly meant to be done naturally for beginning students.

Comment: @Derek, I didn’t mean to mark this question as a duplicate.  I merely wanted to show an approach that might explain the role of $3/2$

Comment: Ok I understand better, I was just wary of the downvote.

Comment: @Derek, I did not downvote

Answer (score 1):

Your base step is problematic.  Please pay attention to the indices.

Base Step:

When $n=0$, we have
$$b_{n+1} = b_1 = 1 \ge \left(\frac32\right)^{n-1} = \left(\frac32\right)^{-1} = \frac23.$$

When $n=1$, we have
$$b_{n+1} = b_2 = 1 \ge \left(\frac32\right)^{n-1} = \left(\frac32\right)^{0} = 1.$$

Induction Step:

When $n \ge 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
b_{n+1}
&= b_{n-1} + b_n \\
&\ge \left(\frac32\right)^{n-3} + \left(\frac32\right)^{n-2} \\
&= \left(\frac32\right)^{n-3} \left(1 + \frac32\right) \\
&= \left(\frac32\right)^{n-3} \frac{10}{4} \\
&\ge \left(\frac32\right)^{n-3} \frac94 \\
&= \left(\frac32\right)^{n-1}.
\end{align*}

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your induction step seems questionable. You did not use the induction hypothesis (or at least it's not clear where you used it). For example, the induction step using the induction hypothesis explicitly my look like this (just a possibility):

By the induction hypothesis, we have $b_m\ge (\frac32)^{m-2}, b_{m-1}\ge(\frac32)^{m-3}$, so $b_{m+1}=b_{m-1}+b_m\ge (\frac32)^{m-3}+(\frac32)^{m-2}=(\frac32)^{m-3}(\frac32+1)=(\frac32)^{m-3}(\frac52)>(\frac32)^{m-3}(\frac32)^2=(\frac32)^{m-1}$, since $\frac52 > \frac94=(\frac32)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, the base case for the induction must be done for $n = 2$ which is easily verified to be true.

Then from $b_{n+1} \geq (\frac{3}{2})^{n-1}$ we get $b_{n}+b_{n+1}=b_{n+2} \,\color{#c00}\geq \frac {3}{2}b_{n+1} \geq (\frac{3}{2})^{n}$ where $\,\color{#c00}\geq$
proves the required induction step.

$b_{n}+b_{n+1} \,\color{#c00} \geq \frac {3}{2}b_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow b_{n} \geq \frac{1}{2}b_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow2b_{n} \geq b_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow b_{n}+b_{n} \geq b_{n-1}+b_{n} \Longleftrightarrow b_{n}\geq b_{n-1} \Longleftrightarrow b_{n-2}+b_{n-1} \geq b_{n-1} \Longleftrightarrow b_{n-2} \color{green}\geq 0 $

for $n> 2$.

To be clear, although $\color{green} \geq $ is trivial, it still must be shown. This follows immediately using strong induction.