# Invalid references when using induction

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

In The Art of Computer Science, Volume I, Section 1.2.1, Knuth discusses Mathematical Induction. He goes over proving the inequality $F_n \leq \phi^{n - 1}$ for all positive integers $n$. 
I would like to have a lengthier discussion on the edge case validity of induction. He shows that the inequality is true for the base case (he calls this step (a)). What confuses me is that his manual verification of P(2) is part of step (b), not (a). I think this has something to do with the fact that the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number is defined recursively with the previous TWO elements, not just one. 
I went on to do exercise 1.2.1.4, and the proof is fairly straightforward, using the same identity that he used: $(1 + \phi) = \phi^2$. However, I'm not sure that it is airtight. The claim and my proof is shown below:

Prove that the Fibonacci numbers satisfy $F_n \geq \phi^{n - 2}$ for all positive integers $n$. $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$, and $F_k = F_{k - 2} + F_{k - 1}$ for $k \geq 2$.
Base Case: Suppose $n = 1$. Then 
$F_n \geq \phi^{n-2}$ 
$F_1 \geq ({\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}})^{-1}$ 
$1 \geq ({\frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{5}}})$, which is true. 
Inductive step: Suppose $F_n \geq \phi^{n - 2}$ is true for $1, ..., n$. We must show that $F_{n + 1} \geq \phi^{n - 1}$ 
(*) We know that $F_{n - 1} \geq \phi^{n - 3}$ and $F_n \geq \phi^{n - 2}$ 
Adding these inequalities, we get $F_{n+1} = F_{n - 1} + F_n \geq \phi^{n - 3} + \phi^{n - 2} = \phi^{n - 3}(1 + \phi) = \phi^{n - 3}\phi^2 = \phi^{n - 1}$ 
So, $F_{n + 1} \geq \phi^{n - 1}$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

My question is, am I being rigorous enough about the set for which some of these statements are valid? For example, in the line (*), I reference $F_{n-1}$, but wouldn't that fall apart in the case $n = 1$? That seems like the wrong line of reasoning, seeing as I could have rephrased as such: Suppose the claim is true for $1, ..., n - 1$. We must show that $F_n \geq \phi^{n - 2}$.

Any discussion is appreciated, particularly one that distinguishes very well between the subscripts used in the claim and the subscripts used in the proof. I want to understand where/if there are any implicit qualifiers for expressions that reference $n$ as a subscript.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589