# Prove the given property of the Fibonacci numbers using the second principle of induction

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am given the property:
$$F(n) > \left(\frac 32\right)^{n - 1},\,\forall n\ge 6$$

I believe I am on the right track by doing:

$$F(6) > \left(\frac 32\right)^5$$

which would be correct, passing the base case

I Then stated my $P(k)$ to be:

$$F(r) > \left(\frac32\right)^{r - 1},\,6\le r\le k$$

Though I am unsure of what to do for my $P(k+1)$ step, and how to prove the inequality through the 2nd principle of induction. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589

Comment: You should also render $F_7>(3/2)^6$, starting perhaps from $64×13=832>729$. Then prove that if $F_k>(3/2)^{k-1}$ and $F_{k+1}>(3/2)^k$, then $F_{k+2}>(5/2)(3/2)^{k-1}$ where $5/2$ is provably $>(3/2)^2$.

Comment: Assume that for all $k\le n, F_{k} > (\frac {3}{2})^k.$  By the definition of the series, $F_{n+1} = F_n + F_{n-1}$  Apply the assumption...$F_{n+1} > (\frac 32)^n + (\frac 32)^{n-1}$ and use algebra to show that  $(\frac 32)^n + (\frac 32)^{n-1} > (\frac 32)^{n+1}$