# proof fibonacci sequence is small o(2^n) without using closed formula

Tags: computational-complexity, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I need to prove that for the given fibonacci sequence,
with initial values:

f(1)=1

f(2)=2

f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)

f(n) is belong to small o(2^n).
I need to prove it without using the closed formula of fibonacci,
or without proving it with generating functions etc.

I need a proof by induction/tree/iterations or something like that.

I proved that it's O(2^n), but can't prove for small o.
I'll appreciated any help.

Comment: How did you prove that it was $O(2^n)$?

Comment: f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)<f(n-1)+f(n-1)=2f(n-1) and so on untill it's smaller than 2^n

Comment: You can easily prove by induction that $$f(n) < 1.9^n$$ Indeed $$f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2) < 1.9^{n-1} + 1.9^{n-2}= 1.9 \cdot \frac{290}{361} < 1.9^n$$

Comment: Note that $$f(n)=2f(n-2)+f(n-3)\leq 3f(n-2).$$ This proves that $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(3^{n/2})$, which is clearly $o(2^n)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1538834/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1343414/589

Comment: @jjagmath ComputerAsker was the one who asked the question, and already knew this, but said they could prove $f(n)=O(2^n)$, and I asked them to explain how.

Comment: @A.M. Sorry, I didn't compare the names.